# Use gson to convert json that should be array of objects, but isn't

Tags: java, json, gson

```
{"myContainer" : 
   { "couldBeAnything" : [
                          {"id":1, "name":"sb", "category":"couldBeAnything"},
                          {"id":2, "name":"bs", "category":"couldBeAnything"}
                         ],
      "somethingElse" : [
                        {"id":1, "name":"sdsa","category":"somethingElse"},
                        {"id":2, "name":"ve","category":"somethingElse"}
                       ]
   },
 "id" : 0
}
```

So far I have :

```
Type myContainerType = new TypeToken<MyContainer>(){}.getType();
MyContainerType myContainerType = gson.fromJson(myJson.getValue(), myContainerType);
```

Where

```
public class MyContainer {
    private int id;
    private Map<String, List<Foo>> foo; // and foo has id, name, category
```

The result, no errors, a populated id field, but just a null map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the json is wrong for the structure `Map<String, List<Foo>>`. When you say map you need not enclose each key-value with `{`. Just put the whole key values in one `{}` and seprate with commas. eg

```
{
  "myContainer": {
    "couldBeAnything": [
      {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sb",
    "category": "couldBeAnything"
      },
      {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "bs",
    "category": "couldBeAnything"
      }
    ],
    "somethingElse": [
      {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "sdsa",
    "category": "somethingElse"
      },
      {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "ve",
    "category": "somethingElse"
      }
    ]
  },
  "id": 0
}
```

With this json it works perfectly

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    String json = "{\"myContainer\":{\"couldBeAnything\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"sb\",\"category\":\"couldBeAnything\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"bs\",\"category\":\"couldBeAnything\"}],\"somethingElse\":[{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"sdsa\",\"category\":\"somethingElse\"},{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"ve\",\"category\":\"somethingElse\"}]},\"id\":0}";

    Map<String, List<Foo>> obj = new HashMap<String, List<Foo>>();
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    obj = gson.fromJson(json, obj.getClass());
    System.out.println(obj);
}
```

Output

```
{id=0.0, myContainer={couldBeAnything=[{id=1.0, name=sb, category=couldBeAnything}, {id=2.0, name=bs, category=couldBeAnything}], somethingElse=[{id=1.0, name=sdsa, category=somethingElse}, {id=2.0, name=ve, category=somethingElse}]}}
```

The issue with your approach was the naming of the field foo. Your json contains the `Map<String, List<Foo>>` name as myContainer. So modify your container class like below and it will work fine :)

```
public class MyContainer {
    private int id;
    private Map<String, List<Foo>> myContainer; 
}
```

Now this will work

```
Type myContainerType = new TypeToken<MyContainer>(){}.getType();
MyContainer myContainer = gson.fromJson(json, myContainerType);
System.out.println(myContainer);
```

Comment: the json mistakes are just typos, the problem is the java structure, have updated question

Comment: um, right, I will double check then. Maybe I am made a noob mistake, as that was the first thing I tried. thanks

Comment: actually it is a bit different, to what I tried, this puts id into a map aswell (which is ok for now) and works. Thanks again. Why doesn't my first version work ?

Comment: Got the issue. It was the problem with field name. updated my answer.. :)

Comment: Ah ok, thankyou (can't accept twice I'm afraid). json conversion always catches me out.